# Why do my views overlap each other?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiview

I just can't understand the views thing and somehow couldn't find one clear solution.

I have a view "A", and it has a button to go to another view "B". View B takes me to view C and view C takes me back to A.

In view C, everywhere that the user taps, he sees an image appear. The code for that is in view C's .m file.

The problem is that when I switch from view C to A, the code for C is still working on view A? If I tap on A, I see that image everywhere I tap, but A is my menu and not part of the game. The method that makes an image appear on a tap belongs only to view C!

I can't understand these views; at the start I used `insertSubview:atIndex:`, and everything was overlapping, so now I use `addSubview:`, and I have this problem.

Can some one explain geometrically how this works?

How come the buttons from view C are seen in view A somtimes without reason? Why, after loading C and back to A, it implements the code of C on view A?

Why do my views overlap all the time? I want every view to work seperately, and not see anything from the views behind it, or implement code from views that were loaded in the past.

Please, help me with my views. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried to read even some basic tutorials on this stuff?

Comment: Tom is right – you should look at using viewcontrollers to present different views to the user. But in the meantime, can you actually post your code? It's hard to say what could be going wrong otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than views, you probably want to focus on UIViewControllers. With this you won't have that problem, a UIViewController is almost always fullscreen and you can code specifically for it. You can create three UIViewController subclasses, one for A, B and C. In each's nib you can add a button, and use this to present the next view controller (possibly using presentModalViewController:). In the third subclass, you can implement your logic for showing an image when the user taps.

Comment: thanks. Tom thats exactly what i do. and yes i have read so much about views .

Answer (score 0):

One good practice, let say you have a

UIViewController *myViewController
with 3 properties :

UIVIew *viewA

UIView *viewB

UIView *viewC

When you want to diplay put a viewA on the stack just set

myViewController.view = viewA;

and so on!

Comment: thats exactly what i did, BUT the .m file of viewC is continue to run while i already showing another view with another .m file. so how does it works anyway? if i did load some .m and then i load another view that connected to another .m , so the first .m is still working ??

Comment: so release the view object when not needed, this is a good practice too to keep as low as possible the number of objects in memory